# mysqlにRuby on Railsのデータベースを作成できません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

mysqlの新しいバージョンを入れたのですが、新しく作成したruby on railsプロジェクトのデータベースを作成しようとしたのですが、mysqlのエラーにより作成できませんでした。

こちらのエラーはmysqlのuser作成の設定に不備があるのでしょうか？

```
rails db:create
Running via Spring preloader in process 6850
Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Couldn't create 'microposts_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 1):

こういうのって `rails` 側の設定と `mysql` 側の設定が不整合なだけの話で、よって

> こちらのエラーはmysqlのuser作成の設定に不備があるのでしょうか？

Yes と言ってもいいし No と言ってもいい。

`rails` の設定として `testuser@localhost` なる DBuser を使うことにしている
`mysql` の設定として `testuser@localhost` なるユーザーは無いか、権限がないか、その他。

`rails` 側の設定を `mysql` にあわせてもよいし
`mysql` 側の設定を `rails` にあわせてもよいっス。方針・仕様次第。

# ンでこの程度の話なら `mysql` でも `mariaDB` でも同じことが同じようにできるはずなので、なぜ異様に苦労してまで `mysql` にこだわるのか理解不能っス。

Comment: ありがとうございます。mysqlの方が慣れていたので、mysqlの方がいいなと思ってmysqlにこだわっていました。もう一度、試してみます。